# rails 3.0.3 activerecord wants to pluralize certain mysql tables all of a sudden

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is in development mode. ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid.  This is an example: I have a model called DisplayAds.  Now activerecord wants to query the table as display_adses instead of display_ads. I have another model called Media. Activerecord use to  query the table medias. Now it wants to query a table called medium.
I know that DisplayAds is not the proper naming convention but it was working until now.

I realize I can fix this by putting set_table_name in the model.
I have not upgraded rails and everything has been working fine for months. 
I have a live production version of this site and it is not experiencing this problem. 
I do git status and I do not see any config files as being modified.

What could I have done to start this happening? How can I stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you recently upgraded from 2.3.5/8 to 3.0.x?  I had the same problem (same thing with medias).

You'll want to add irregular [Inflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html) in your `config/initializers/inflections.rb` file

```
 ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
    inflect.irregular 'media', 'medias'
    inflect.irregular 'display_ad', 'display_ads'
    ...
 end
```

Comment: Its been 3.0.3 since the beginning. Never upgraded. Strange  it works on the production live server. I guess maybe I should just fix it and push it live before the live server starts doing it too.

Comment: Did you try adding the inflection to `config/initializers/inflections.rb` i messed up path originally?

Comment: I just used set_table_name in the model.